# How do I login into the admin page if I disable password?

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a passwordless app (using token auth from DRF so login using email otp, social auth etc) so my user model has password = none.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',
                          unique=True, blank=False, max_length=60)
username = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='username', blank=False, unique=True, max_length=20)
first_name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='first name', blank=False, unique=False, max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name='last name', blank=False, unique=False, max_length=20)
password = None
```

Now how do login in the admin page because it requires a password

Answer (score 0):

Once your user connect with a valid token, call `auth.login(request, user)`

Note: add backend class to the user before calling login e.g.

```
   user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering however I figured out what I was doing wrong. I only had token auth in DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES by adding basic auth too in there I was able to make and login admin user with password